# Pass Python/JAVA/Perl option using shell command

Tags: java, python, perl, ubuntu

I am using several programs written in JAVA, Pyhton, and Perl, invoking them via command line.

I am often performing the same task on multiple files and I would like use a

```
for
```

loop instead.
However, there are some program options that should be adjusted for each file. I thought to store the strings describing the options in text files and copy them into the flag corresponding to the option.
For example for a python program:

```
python <Prog_X.py> input -option1 xxxx -option2 <here I want to copy content of File.txt> -out
```

I am not quite sure how to do that. Maybe it is a basic thing but I cannot find a way around it.

Any idea how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the option file contain only a single line you could do

```
python <Prog_X.py> input -option1 xxxx -option2 $(cat option.txt) -out
```

Comment: Great! So there is a way!The problem is that I have to specify the line where the string is, can I write a python or bash script and call it in the option flag?

Answer (score 0):

I have already created a file copier for only read text files for java sometime ago, so all you have to do is just change the java code in it to the other languages and confirm that it works

I've only ran it in JCreator so I don't know how it'll work on something else

[`File Copier Code`](http://ideone.com/g7mRZ1)